# self contained app not publishing runtimes

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019, asp.net-core-3.1

I have made an asp .net core 3.1 web application, it runs on localhost with no issues. When I want to publish my app I run into an issue:

```
HTTP Error 500.32 - ANCM Failed to Load dll.
```

After some analyzing, I found that when publishing the runtime folders do not publish to the remote server, altough the target runtime has been selected. I checked the publish profile just to be sure and there the runtime identifier is also in the document
[image: publishing settings in visual studio 2019]

Comment: I suggest you could click the produce single file and delete all existing files prior to publish and try again.

Comment: The hosting server doesn't allow single file publishing